# C++ inheritance: protected variables not available

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

I've got the following C++ code in XCode, giving two errors I cannot make sense of:

```
#include <iostream>


class Buch{
public:
    Buch (long int nummer = 0, char autor[25] = (char*)"", int jahr = 0, bool ausgel = false);

    long int getNr();
    int getJahr();

protected:
    long int __nummer;
    char     __autor[25];
    int      __jahr;
    bool     __ausgel;

    void setAusl(bool x);
    bool getAusl();
};

class FachBuch : Buch {
public:
    void setSWort(int sw);
    int getSWort();

protected:
    char     __fach[15];
    int      __swort;
};

class UBuch : Buch {
public:
    void setAlter(int a);
    int getAlter();

protected:
    int      __kateg;
    char     __land[15];

private:
    int _ab_alter;
};

class Bildband : UBuch {
public:
    Bildband(long int nummer = 0, char autor[25] = (char*)"", int jahr = 0, int kategorie = 0, char land[15] = (char*)"");
};

Buch::Buch (long int nummer, char autor[25], int jahr, bool ausgel) {
    __nummer = nummer;
    //_autor = autor;
    __jahr = jahr;
    __ausgel = ausgel;
}

long int Buch::getNr() {
    return __nummer;
}

int Buch::getJahr() {
    return __jahr;
}

void Buch::setAusl(bool x) {
    __ausgel = x;
}

bool Buch::getAusl() {
    return __ausgel;
}


void FachBuch::setSWort(int x) {
    __swort = x;
}

int FachBuch::getSWort() {
    return __swort;
}


void UBuch::setAlter(int x) {
    _ab_alter = x;
}

int UBuch::getAlter() {
    return _ab_alter;
}

Bildband::Bildband(long int nummer, char autor[25], int jahr, int kategorie, char land[15]) {

    __nummer = nummer; // error message: Cannot cast 'Bildband' to its private base class 'Buch'

    //Buch(nummer, autor, jahr, false); // error message: '__nummer' is a private member of 'Buch'

}

int main () {
    Bildband Masuren(356780, (char*)"Kranz", 2010, 4, (char*)"Polen");
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following errors:
main.cpp:92:5: Cannot cast 'Bildband' to its private base class 'Buch'
main.cpp:92:5: '__nummer' is a private member of 'Buch'

My knowledge of C++ is quite limited and I had no luck googling, probably mainly because I lack the necessary C++ basic knowledge.

Can anyone explain to me why these errors occur and what terms I need to look up to understand the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is the part you don't understand, but are you aware you're using private inheritance?

Comment: The term you need to look up is `protected`

Comment: Names containing adjacent underscores are [reserved identifiers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier).

Comment: Presumably, `class FachBuch : Buch` should have been `class FachBuch : public Buch`.

Comment: Alternatively, `struct FachBuch : Buch`.

Answer (score 9):

They are not available because `UBuch` inherits `Buch` *privately*.  When defining a class, inheritance is private by default.

```
// These two lines mean the same thing:
class UBuch : Buch
class UBuch : private Buch
```

All members of `Buch` are inherited, but those visible to `UBuch` are inherited as *private to `UBuch`*.

This means that code external to `UBuch` has no access to any members of `Buch` on `UBuch` objects, nor can it convert pointers or references to `UBuch` objects to pointers or references to `Buch`.

**This includes classes that derive `UBuch`.**

```
class Bildband : UBuch
```

Even though `Buch` is in the inheritance chain, its members were inherited privately by `UBuch`, and so `Bildband` has no access to the members inherited from `Buch`.

To fix this, you should inherit `Buch` publicly (and you probably want all of your other classes to inherit publicly from their respective base classes, too):

```
class UBuch : public Buch
```

Also, note that identifiers containing two consecutive underscores are reserved by the environment, so all such identifiers in your code (`__nummer`, `__autor`, etc.) cause *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't define an access-specifier, the compiler will default to private inheritance for classes. Simply prefix your UBuch class and Buch class with "public" like so:

```
// ...
class UBuch : public Buch {
// ...
class Bildband : public UBuch {
```

I assume "public" here, since I guess that you want to provide access to the methods like getNr / getJahr from users of BildBand as well.

./regards
Florian

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: See comments below

The type of inheritance effects which members are inherited:

**public** inheritance means only public members are inherited.

**protected** inheritance means public members are inherited and protected members are inherited as protected as well.

**private** inheritance means public members are inherited and protected members are inherited as private.

Here you are inheriting privately by default.

Comment: No, public inheritance means that **all** members are inherited.

Comment: private members are never inherited.
protected members are not inherited by public

Comment: They are inherited, but not visible to the deriving class (otherwise they would not exist). And even if I grant that, `public` also causes `protected` members to be inherited as `protected`, otherwise further-derived classes could not use a grandparent's `protected` members.

Comment: To put it another way, a class always inherits all members from its parent classes, but does not inherit *access* to the private ones.

Comment: You are right! Thanks for correcting me! Sorry for the confusion! I'll edit the answer

Comment: I believe the following link summarizes the answer quite well:
http://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/public-protected-private-inheritance